# Having Issue on Targeting Interior Table Using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jLfu3tse/) and let me know why I am not able to change background color of each table related to upper button?

```
$(function () {
    $('button[type="submit"]').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('table').css("background-color", "yellow");
       // $(this).closest('.panel-body').find('.table').css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
});
```

As you can see I already tried:

```
 $(this).closest('table').css("background-color", "yellow");
```

and

```
 $(this).closest('.panel-body').find('.table').css("background-color", "yellow");
```

but they are not doing the job?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**jQuery Documentation - `.closest()` method**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
>
> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and ***traversing up through its ancestors*** in the DOM tree.

The reason it isn't working is because the `button` element isn't inside of the `table` element. The `.closest()` method will therefore never find the `table`.

You could find the closest `.panel` ancestor, and then find the `table` element from there:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wqomfdea/)

```
$('button[type="submit"]').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.panel').find('table').css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```